# Find minimum absolute difference of elements in numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have an array of arrays of shape (n, m), as well as an array b of shape (m). I want to create an array c containing distances to the closest element. I can do it with this code:

```
a = [[11, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 6, 1, -2]]
b = [1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
c = []

for inner in range(len(a[0])):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    for outer in range(len(a)):
        current_distance = abs(b[inner] - a[outer][inner])
        if min_distance > current_distance:
            min_distance = current_distance
    c.append(min_distance)

# c=[3, 1, 6, 1, 2]
```

Elementwise iteration is very slow. What is the numpy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, I think that this would do:

```
>>> c = np.min(np.abs(np.array(a) - b), axis = 0)
>>> c
array([3, 1, 6, 1, 2])
```